# Resize image with grouped label

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In `diagrams.net` (formerly known as `draw.io`), I can easily group an image and label together. There are even built-in shapes which accomplish this. For example:

[image: good_resize]

I would like to resize the shape, such that:

- The image continues to fill the container
- The space between the label and image remain constant
- The font-size of the label remains constant

However, even when holding `shift` to keep the aspect-ratio, the image remains the same size with awkward whitespace occurring:

[image: bad_resize]

How do I achieve the desired resizing? This seems possible in other diagramming software, such as [whimsical.com](https://whimsical.com/).

Here is the full diagram code:

```
<mxGraphModel dx="782" dy="447" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="827" pageHeight="1169" math="0" shadow="0">
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0" />
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
    <mxCell id="agnOd5MOz-EUEwHnS-w4-2" value="Label" style="label;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=bottom;spacingLeft=0;spacingBottom=4;imageAlign=center;imageVerticalAlign=top;image=img/clipart/Gear_128x128.png" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="110" y="40" width="80" height="80" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tick "Constrain proportion" (can be seen in Arrange tab on the right when a shape is selected), does it help?

If not, could you copy/paste diagram data so it can be tested directly? You can make a test diagram only with shapes in question (just click Extras > Edit diagram and copy/paste the code).

Comment: Constraining the diagram has the same effect as holding down `shift`, which unfortunately does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create two shapes, the rectangle and the image (child). Now for the child shape enable the resizeWidth and resizeHeight properties.

Try entering this example as the diagram:
https://pastebin.com/ayBstZ14